# Creating Voronoi polygons diagram that are limited to a bounding box

Tags: python, voronoi

I want to get a Voronoi polygon diagram for a set of points within 50 X 50 domain. That os all the voronoi ridges should be clipped at edges of bounding box, and voronoi vertices should lie on edges or within the bounding box.[However this i the image I am getting by using scipy.spatial.Voronoi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt0qs.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to cut off at the box boundaries all those cells that would extend beyond it is to do the following:

1. Reflect your original data set (your "Voronoi seeds") across each edge of your box, creating, in this case, 4 new data sets, each one being a mirror image of your original set of points across one of the edges.
2. Regard your original data set and these four new data sets as all one set of points, and run your Voronoi algorithm to create a Voronoi partition with this new, enlarged set. Those points in the original set whose cells would extend beyond the boundary now will be met by their mirror images, and their cells will be cut off exactly at the boundaries as you wish.
3. Now simply ignore the extra points generated in step 1, and you have a Voronoi partition of the original bounding box using only your original set of points, with the cells near the edge neatly cut off by the boundary of the box.

The reflection step is not hard; I can elaborate if necessary.

This method does multiply your number of points by 5, which increases the time to complete the Voronoi computation, obviously. Depending on your number of points, this could become an issue. One can speed things up by reflecting only those points whose cells actually extend beyond the box; that takes a bit more logic but is do-able.